# Java Question about Copy Constructor

Tags: java

I hope you will help me understand this `Copy Constructor` I took more then 2 hours reading reading on websites and I didn't understand anything about it.

I know that a copy constructor is used to copy an object of a class. But I don't understand the code of the copy consturctor.

For Example:

```
public class Rectangle 
{
    private double length = 10.0;
    private double width = 10.0;


    public Rectangle(double length, double width){
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;

    }
   //this is the copy constructor  what exactly the argument here? is it the object ref it self? please explain what happening here. and the use

    public Rectangle(Rectangle ref){
        this.length = ref.length;
        this.width = ref.width;
    }
```

this is what I see all the time. but I don't understand the code at all!
`ref` is it going to be created in the main program?

let say this is the main program

```
public class rectangleTest{ 
public static void main(String[] args){
//is this new_ref object going to be created here?

Rectangle new_ref = new Rectangle(10.0 , 10.0);
```

This thing will not 100% clear to me unless if someone make a small class and main class showing me what's happening

Thank you.

Comment: Let's say this never compiles: `Rectangle new ref = new ref(10.0 , 10.0);`

Comment: I think he meant Rectangle new ref = new Rectangle (10.0 , 10.0);

Comment: Yes! I'm really sorry guys I was panicking :S  Thanks @stas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ref` isn't the name of a *class*; it's the name of the *parameter* to the second constructor. So the `main` method would actually look like this:

```
Rectangle foo = new Rectangle(10.0 , 10.0);

// Create another Rectangle with the same width and height
Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(foo);
```

Note that objects don't have *names* - variables do. Here the value of the `foo` variable becomes the value of the `ref` parameter in the second constructor, when that constructor is invoked in the last line above. Also note that the values of `foo`, `bar` and `ref` *aren't* objects... they're references to objects.

Comment: do you know anything about verlet physics? lol im asking because your the all time #1 user apparently and i have to a question that no one could answer yet

Comment: I should've asked SOF instead of wasting 2 hours. @Jon and everyone this is really helped me so so much! Thank you! and I'm sorry I made a mistake in the code and @stas fixed it for me.

Comment: @stas Yep maybe someone should ask a quantum mechanics question on SO - that way we'd finally get a deeper understanding of our universe: Either we find out more about physics or can finally decide if Jon is omniscient or not ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your "copy constructor" like this

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle (3.0, 4.0);
Rectangle b = new Rectangle (a);
```

NOTA BENE: Unlike in C++ where a copy ctor is part of the language and called implicitely, the following example in Java will NOT call your copy ctor, but just assign the reference.

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle (3.0, 4.0);
Rectangle b = a;
```

In your case, I would prefer to implement a clone method.

Comment: Thank you!!! So this is what they call it a privacy leak? In the second part of your code. When I changed the value of `b.getLength()` the value of the length is also changed in object `a` .

Comment: Why should GETlength change something? But yes a and b refer in the 2nd example to the same instance. Evrything you do to a, you do it to b too.

Answer (score 0):

The names don't matter.  The  name just refers to an object, so when you pass it into a method it just used a different name.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a `clone()`, it duplicates your object so that you have two different instances  but which are equal.